# GMaps API KMLLayer with GeoRss can't create my own file

Tags: google-maps, rss

I'm trying to get the georss example from here to work:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers

Actually, it works fine as written, but I want to create my own georss file, so I downloaded the referred-to flickr georss thing as a whole, and uploaded it to my own godaddy server. I can see that file fine, and when I d/l it, and diff it with the original, they are identical.

But when I replace my own server's url for the one in the example, it doesn't work. No error produced, just nothing! Is there some reason that I can't just point the georss kmllayer thing to a file instead of a formal feed??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be easier to help when you post the URL of the file

Comment: 1. If you enter the URL for _your_ version of the feed in a browser, does it find it or does it give a "page no found" response? 2. Have you configured the [MIME types for that type of file on your server](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut?hl=en#kml_server)? I found I needed to use a .xml extension on GoDaddy's servers until I configured the MIME type correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,using .xml worked. (Modulo various caching nightmares!)

Thanks! (I'm the same user as the OP, but now I have my own account, rather than using a guest account.)